# Node.js to frontend data sending failed

Tags: python, node.js, d3.js

I want my Node.js get request to send data from python to the front end. And res.send has been called just once. However, process.stdout.on gets called multiple times, thus giving me the cannot set headers error. I want the server code to send the entire data in one go without process.stdout.on being called multiple times. What am I doing wrong?

I tried making the code synchronous. However, it doesn't work. Also, I tried calling the process.stdout.on function just once using an if condition of if headers have not been sent. This also doesn't let the entire result from the python code to be sent to the front end which is in d3.js.

```
app.get('/fetch_slider_val/:sliderVal',(req,res)=>{
    var sliderVal = req.params.sliderVal
    var X = sliderVal.split(" ")
    var sites = X[0].split(',')
    var date1 = X[1]
    var date2 = X[2]
    var normKey = X[3]
    var normEnt = X[4]

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var process = spawn('python',['sql_data_retrieve.py',sites,date1,date2,normKey,normEnt]);
    console.log('1 out')
    i = 0
    process.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(res.headersSent) #false and becomes true after the next console.log(res.headersSent) gives true. somehow, this function is called again. 
        res.send(data.toString()) #some data sent not all 
        console.log(res.headersSent) #true
    })
})
```

I expect the entire data.toString() to be sent to front end. However, just half of it is sent and I end up with this error message.

```
_http_outgoing.js:470
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/amishr45/PycharmProjects/NewsVis/TrialVis/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/amishr45/PycharmProjects/NewsVis/TrialVis/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/amishr45/PycharmProjects/NewsVis/TrialVis/app_retrieve.js:103:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```